# Submitting a Form Template for User Authentication

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am creating a signin using Django. I having a problem at `if request.method == 'POST':`. When submitting the form to the script below, the form redirect to the else statement(goes to google) instead of the post method. My template file is below.

**Django Script:**

```
def signup(request): 
    username = email = password = repassword = ''

    try:
        redirect_to = request.GET.get('next','/')
    except ValueError:
        redirect_to = "/"

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            repassword = form.cleaned_data['repassword']
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('http://www.google.com/')

    return render(request,'signup.html',{'form':form})
```

**Template File:**

```
 {% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}Sign Up{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<br></br>
<div class = "container">
   <form action="/signup/" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <br></br>
        <div class="control-group">
            <p>
                USERNAME
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="text" name = "username" value = "" id ="username"/>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <p>
                EMAIL 
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="text" name = "email" value = "" id= "email"/>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <p>
                PASSWORD
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="password" name = "password" value="" id="password"/>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <p>
                RE-ENTER PASSWORD 
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="password" name = "repassword" value="" id="repassword" />
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-primary " value="Sign me Up!"/>
        </div>  
    </form>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Did you check whether you are getting a POST in the request? Is the 'redirect to google' else clause correctly indented (that is, it is nor an else clause of the is_valid)

Comment: @zaphod the code is correctly indented and structured. How would I check if I am getting a POST in the request?

Comment: You can put an `assert 0` in your code anywhere, and then if you have `Debug = True` in your `settings.py`, Django will print out a lot of debugging information and you can see the request, local vars and so on.

Comment: @zaphod I included "assert 0" before the request. I get that "No GET" or "No POST". So I guessing that post data is not being received. How would I fix this? is it a problem in the html?

Comment: I don't see a `</form>` tag in your template. Is that the full html form?

Comment: @rantanplan that was only a piece. I updated with the full html.

Comment: moments ago the `action` of your form was completely different. Is there a possibility you're having multiple view functions and url patterns and that you've just mixed them up? So that you're debugging the wrong view function?

Comment: @rantanplan sorry for that. that was older version. I updated with current html that I using now.

Comment: Is there a possibility you have mixed tabs and spaces in your file? Because your code seems fine.

Comment: @rantanplan  no.everything is structured perfectly. I tried an "assert 0" before the "request.method = POST". The output showed that no POST data is being pushed into the call. could it be the html that the problem?

Comment: Can you just try this: Remove the form code in your template and replace it with {{ form.as_p }}, remove the action, enctype and just leave `<form method="POST">` --> basically simplify the code for now and see what happens. If it works, you can view source of the page and compare with your code.

Comment: Also, in your views code, in the last line where you call `render`, you are passing it a `form` which might not be initialized. Thats not the issue you are seeing here, but just bringing it to your notice

Comment: Actually @zaphod raised a valid point. There is no way you're invoking the correct view function, since the `form` inside `render` should raise a `NameError` when rendering the form. It is not defined nowhere at that point. Please check your code from urls.py to views.py again.